# SSMS can't open data file

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Im trying to import a .csv file in SQL Server Management Studio using the import export wizard.

I just created a database and when I used the wizard I ran into several errors. This is the error log.

```
Pre-execute (Error)
Messages
Information 0x402090dc: Data Flow Task 1: The processing of file "G:\SLIIT\3 YEAR\2 SEM\DWBI\assignment\datasource\steam_description_data.csv" has started.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Information 0x402090dc: Data Flow Task 1: The processing of file "G:\SLIIT\3 YEAR\2 SEM\DWBI\assignment\datasource\steam_description_data.csv" has started.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Warning 0x80070020: Data Flow Task 1: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020200e: Data Flow Task 1: Cannot open the datafile "G:\SLIIT\3 YEAR\2 SEM\DWBI\assignment\datasource\steam_description_data.csv".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 1: Source - steam_description_data_csv failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I don't have the file open with any other programs so i'm unsure why it even said it was being used by another program.

any way to fix this?

Comment: Where are you running SSMS from, in relation to the server where SSIS/SQL Server is running? Your desktop? The server itself? An intermediate server?

Comment: I use my desktop

Comment: The server is trying to resolve that path, but it can't because it's mapped only on your desktop. You need to specify the UNC path to the file and the service account(s) the server is running under need access to it.

Comment: I try to use import flat file instead of import data and it worked